# get the __FILE__ value of calling feature spec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'd like to have something like this in `create_new_item_spec.rb`:

```
feature "task012: create new item #{ff}", task012: true do
```

and have this in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
def ff
  "features/#{File.basename(__FILE__)}"
end
```

but this gives me:

```
 task012: create new item in features/spec_helper.rb
```

How would I call this to give me `features/create_new_item_spec.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) method to get the source location of the caller, e.g.:

```
def ff
  file, line, _ = caller.first.split(/:/)
  "features/#{File.basename(file)}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def ff; caller_locations.first.path end
```

Comment: It was introduced recently. :)